# Tiles in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

My project use Apache Tiles
in my tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="index" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/templateuser.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp" />
</definition>
.......
</tiles-definitions>
```

i configed viewResolver in dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-mvel</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-autotag-core-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-mustache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-servlet-wildcard</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-request-velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-velocity</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

i put  .jsp, .html, .css etc.. file in the correct dirctory. When i run the code, i get the error
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: I/O Error reading definitions.
I don't know why?

Comment: As the error tells you /WEB-INF/tiles.xml cannot be read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If you are using `tiles2`**, `viewClass` property value should be `tiles2`, change it to

```
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
```

And `tilesConfigurer` also should be kind of tiles2,

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  ...
</bean>
```

Otherwise **if you want to use `tiles3`**, you need to change DTD version to `tiles3` relevant like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
      "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 4):

if you use tiles3 make sure you have

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
      "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
```

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd"> 
tiles.xml
```

Another thing, you don't notice this point when you have internet connexion because the validation will go throught otherwise.